# Setting a field collection default value for a field using form

Tags: entities

I'm trying to set up a default value programmatically to my field which is in field collection. This has proved quite hard and I cant seem to get around it. Any assistance will be appreciated. This is the code i have tried to far without any success.This field is a select list with different select items. Now i want it to pre-select one of the items.

```
$field_collect = $form["field_fielc_collection_group"][LANGUAGE_NONE]; 

                            foreach ($field_collect as $fielders){
                                        if(is_array($fielders)){
                                        $somethin = $fielders["field_to_set_default"][LANGUAGE_NONE]["#default_value"];
                                        $default_val =array(t('something'));
                            array_push($somethin,$default_val);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I resolved this.

```
$language = $form['field_fielc_collection_group']["#language"];
                    $iterates = $form['field_fielc_collection_group'][$language];

                foreach($iterates as $multi__key => $iterate){
                            if (is_integer($multi__key)){
                                        if(is_array($iterate)){
                                            $delt = $form['field_fielc_collection_group'][$language][$multi__key]["#delta"];
$form["field_fielc_collection_group"][$language][$multi__key]["field_to_set_default"][$language]["#default_value"][$delt] = 'default_value' ;
                                        }
                            }
                }
```